# How to extract integers from a separated string in java

Tags: java, string, sum

Examples of the String

```
131-5923-213
1421-41-4-12-4
1-1
```

How would I extract the integers into an Array or find the sum of these integers? My code so far goes

```
int hyphenCount = socialNum.length()-socialNum.replaceAll("-", "").length();

ArrayList<Integer> sum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i < hyphenCount; i++)
{
   //my brain is too small             
}
```

What I want to do is make a function like the following

```
public void extractSum(String s)
{
  int outputSum;

  //stuff

  return outputSum;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java#3481842

Comment: `Arrays.stream(inputString.split("-")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();` ?

Comment: Is the "sum" of `131-5923-213` meant to be `131 + 5923 + 213 = 6267`, or  `1 + 3 + 1 + 5 + 9 + 2 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 3 = 30`?

Comment: @KevinAnderson I guess OP is looking for the first one

Answer (score 0):

Using Streams you can do:

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(str.replace("-",  "").split("")).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();
```

Which will replace the hyphen and then split each character, parse the integer, and return the sum

***Output:*** (For the `String` `"131-5923-213"`)

```
30
```

If you want the sum of `131` + `5923` + `213` you could do:

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(str.split("-")).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();
```

Which will split on a hyphen, parse the integers, and return the sum

Comment: I think the OP is asking `131 + 5923 + 213 = 6267`

Comment: @Kartik I edited in a solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [@GBlodgett's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53219342/8071889) answer using stream, you could simply run a `for` loop to calculate the sum.

```
String string = "131-5923-213";

String[] num = string.split("-");  //<----num[0] = "131" ,num[1]="5923",num[2] = "213"

int hyphenCount = num.length;  //<----it would give you 3 as length

int mySum = 0;   //initialize the sum as 0

for(int i = 0; i < hyphenCount; i++)
{
     mySum+= Integer.parseInt(num[i]); //<---convert the string to an int

}
```

> Output: 6267